# Visual Studio Publish Requires App Pool Refresh

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, publish

Currently, each time I publish changes to my web app I need to refresh the app pool for the changes to take effect. I would manually copy over the new app DLL into the bin directory to refresh it.

Googling brought up this (not sure if this is actually an answer to my question):

[Changes in ascx / aspx files - will it reset application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014600/changes-in-ascx-aspx-files-will-it-reset-application#5014789)

> if Shadow Copy is enabled, the application will reset only when you recycle the application pool

However I didn't enable shadow copy AFAIK. Currently I have "precompile during publishing" checked, as well as "allow precompiled site to be updateable" checked.

Are there any other causes of this behavior other than shadow copying enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not caching the web site in your browser?

Make sure your browser is checking for the latest site version such as here on IE:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure. I always reload without cache (and just to make sure the ctrl+f5 is working in Chrome, I tried it in IE as well).